# Sudden degradation in LINQ to SQL stored procedure performance from ASP.NET site, including timeouts

Tags: sql, asp.net, performance, linq, sql-server-2008-r2

The site is ASP.NET 2.0, using LINQ to SQL. Database is SQL Server 2008 R2.

Been working on an issue where performance suddenly took a huge drop one day and has remained that way since.  Cannot figure out why.  It has been just certain functionality of the site, not necessarily a site-wide problem.  Have focused on a particular stored procedure in general that is taking a good 1000ms+ showing in profiler.  When copying the TextData and running right in the query analyzer, it runs much quicker.

Have tried a sp_recompile on the stored procedure as well as the table used. The db server was restarted during a maintenance period and that also did not stabilize things. Is there any possible troubleshooting steps anyone could provide to help dig deeper on this?  Absolutely stumped.

Comment: you know you are providing very little information other than it runs slow. Generally speaking do profiling on your sql server to see how much is going on there. any network issues that slows things down? any wildy varying data sets being queried (and you should have included a OPTIMIZE UNKNOWN in you stored procedure)

Answer (score 0):

It could be a parameter sniffing problem. You can see the details here - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/turgays/archive/2013/09/10/parameter-sniffing-problem-and-workarounds. As suggested in the blog, you can try the following -

OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@VARIABLE=VALUE))

OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@VARIABLE UNKNOWN))

Use local variables - Basically declare local variables and assign the value of the parameter to local variable and use the local variable in the query.

OPTION (RECOMPILE) - Since you have already tried that you can ignore this

Could you post the query snippet which is causing this issue?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions so far... I can post later when I can gain access to the db server.. but in the meantime I'll say that the system has been running for months now, and hasn't had a huge slowdown like this before. If it was parameter sniffing, wouldn't this have shown itself much earlier in time?

Comment: @user1560457 Not necessarily, that's the nature of this issue. We had a similar problem where the stored proc taking 1-2 seconds for about 2 years suddenly started taking ~70-90 seconds. We have used the local variable option to solve that issue. It would also help us if you share the table schema and the query used in the stored proc, as we can see if it is because of some indexes no longer being used by the query optimizer. I hope you had already tried the basic trouble shooting steps like rebuilding the indexes etc.,

Comment: issue solved, turns out it was completely unrelated to anything in SQL, but at least I learned about these for future troubleshooting. It was issue related to the virtual server. Thanks.